# How can I find the id of a gang in OpenACC?

Tags: openacc

In OpenMP I can use `omp_get_thread_num()` to get the numerical id of the thread executing the code.

Is there a similar function I can use in OpenACC to get id of the gang executing a piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenACC standard does not yet include such a function, but, with the PGI compiler, you can use the compiler extension function `__pgi_gangidx()` as follows:

```cpp
//pgc++ -fast -acc -ta=tesla,cc60 -Minfo=accel test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "openacc.h"

int main(){
  int gangs = 100;
  int *ids  = new int[gangs];

  //Ensure everything is zeroed
  for(int i=0;i<gangs;i++)
    ids[i] = 0;

  #pragma acc parallel num_gangs(gangs) copyout(ids[0:gangs])
  {
    ids[__pgi_gangidx()] = __pgi_gangidx();
  }

  for(int i=0;i<gangs;i++)
    std::cout<<ids[i]<<" ";
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Compile with:

```
pgc++ -fast -acc -ta=tesla,cc60 -Minfo=accel test.cpp
```

This gives as output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```

as expected.

A suite of additional functions are available:

```cpp
extern int __pgi_gangidx(void);
extern int __pgi_workeridx(void);
extern int __pgi_vectoridx(void);
extern int __pgi_blockidx(int);
extern int __pgi_threadidx(int);
```

Note that `omp_get_thread_num()` does not (yet?) work for GPU-targeted code.