# Using `__pgi_gangidx()` within a parallel-section loop

Tags: c++, openacc, pgi

The `__pgi_gangidx()` compiler extension function is supposed to return the numerical id of the gang executing the function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350062/how-can-i-find-the-id-of-a-gang-in-openacc/48350098#48350098)). However, I've been unable to figure out how to use it within a parallel-section loop.

In the code below, I try several possibilities, only one of which yields the desired answer. This one, unfortunately, runs my parallel section loop sequentially.

The variable `int place` is a stand-in for more complicated gang-specific references to several global arrays, so it is not easily removed.

The code can be compiled with:

```
pgc++ -fast -acc -ta=tesla,cc60 -Minfo=accel test.cpp
```

**Code:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "openacc.h"

void ResetIds(int *const ids, int size){
  //Ensure everything is zeroed
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    ids[i] = 0;  
}

void ShowVector(int line, int *const ids, int size){
  std::cout<<"Line "<<line<<": ";
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    std::cout<<ids[i]<<" ";
  std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
  int gangs  = 10;
  int gwidth = 10;
  int size   = gangs*gwidth;
  int *ids   = new int[50*size];

  //Works!
  //Gives: 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14
  ResetIds(ids, size);
  #pragma acc parallel num_gangs(gangs) copy(ids[0:size])
  {
    int place = __pgi_gangidx();
    #pragma acc loop seq
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      ids[place*gwidth+i] = 14;
  }  
  ShowVector(__LINE__, ids, size);

  //Gives: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ResetIds(ids, size);
  #pragma acc parallel num_gangs(gangs) copy(ids[0:size])
  {
    int place = __pgi_gangidx()*gwidth;
    #pragma acc loop 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      ids[place+i] = 14;
  } 
  ShowVector(__LINE__, ids, size);

  //Gives: 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  ResetIds(ids, size);
  #pragma acc parallel num_gangs(gangs) copy(ids[0:size])
  {
    int place = __pgi_gangidx();
    #pragma acc loop
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      ids[place*gwidth+i] = 14;
  }  
  ShowVector(__LINE__, ids, size);

  //Gives: 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14
  ResetIds(ids, size);
  #pragma acc parallel num_gangs(gangs) copy(ids[0:size])
  {
    int place = __pgi_gangidx();
    #pragma acc loop worker
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      ids[place*gwidth+i] = 14;
  }  
  ShowVector(__LINE__, ids, size);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the late reply.  I was away at a conference so missed your post.

"__pgi_gangidx()" is working correctly.  The problem here is a misunderstanding on what the "loop" directive is doing.

In the first case, you've added "seq" to the loop directive forcing the loop to be run sequentially.  Since it's in a parallel region, the loop is run in "gang-redundant" mode and all gangs will execute the loop.  In other words, the loop is actually executed 100 times.  (Note that I consider this bad practice since the code would get different result if run sequentially without OpenACC)

In the other cases, you don't specify "seq".  Hence the loop will be parallelized across all gangs and vectors and will be run only 10 times.  Since the vector length is 128 but the loop trip count is 10, only one gang will actually update the array and only in 10 elements.

Comment: Thanks, Mat! Hope you had a good conference. So the latter code blocks (without `seq`) are closer to being correct. If I follow you correctly, setting `vector_length(10)` should resolve my problem; I've now done so in all the parallel sections, but the first part of the array remains the only part filled in.

Comment: (I'm trying to simulate large gang-independent memories by dividing up the global array between the gangs, so I'm interested in having them behave as independently as possible.)

Comment: You'd actually need to set the vector length to 1 in order to get the loop to partition across all 10 gangs.  At 10, the loop iterations will all still go to a single gang.

Comment: I'm thinking that you'll want an outer loop with a trip count equal to the number of gangs then an inner loop for the vector dimension.